# How to use SSIS to delete rows from a local table based on conditions from remote?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a Data Flow Transformation which uses SQL Server source and SQL Server destination(two separate servers). I need to Delete rows from Target SQL Database based on a condition using a table from Source. I don't want to use the Linked servers as it will become a dependency for deploying the SSIS project also access rights issues.

If it is SSMS, I believe I must use the linked server, is it possible to avoid linked server with in SSIS?

> **The smaple TSQL is**
>   DELETE T2 FROM dbProd.dbo.Table2 T2
>   
> JOIN LINKED_SERVER.dbStage.dbo.Table1 T1 ON T1.RowID = T2.RowID

I would be grateful for any helpful answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SSIS data flow task to `insert` the data you need to delete (unique row identifiers or conditions only) into the local table and then execute `delete` based on that transferred data.

```
DELETE T2 FROM dbProd.dbo.Table2 T2 
JOIN dbProd.dbo.local_copy_of_dbStage_Table1 T1 ON T1.RowID = T2.RowID
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution proposed by @AndreyMorozov will work, and if you need to avoid creating a staging table on the destination server, another way is to use an ExecuteSQL transformation as your DataFlow destination, and execute a DELETE statement on the Destination Server for each row in the DataFlow (which came from the Source Server).

You do not need to use Linked Servers with SSIS, as long as the SSIS server can connect to both servers through an OLEDB connection string.

Comment: indeed, you can use a pair of `OLE DB Source` connected to the remote server and [OLE DB Command Transformation](http://www.sqlis.com/sqlis/post/OLE-DB-Command-Transformation.aspx) task with parameterized delete statement inside, executed for each row from the source. It will work, but quite slow for big datasets.

Comment: Thanks.. this works too, but as mentioned it is slow for large data sets.

Comment: Yes, Andrey's solution is better, as long as you are able to create staging tables on the destination server.